# Not understanding the 'volatile' keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

This is a Thread Class.

```
public class Processor extends Thread {

    public  boolean running = true;
    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main invoker class

```
public class ProcessorInvoker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Processor proc1= new Processor();
        proc1.start(); // ---->assuming thread0
        Processor proc2=new Processor();
        proc2.start(); // ---->assuming thread1

        proc1.running=false;
    }
}
```

What my understanding of keyword volatile is: When the boolean variable in the Processor class is NOT VOLATILE then value of this variable changed to 'false' won't affect thread1 because the changed value to false-->proc1.running=false is not seen by thread1 , so thread1 keeps on running but thread0 stops.

When the boolean variable is made VOLATILE what I understood was since I changed the value of boolean variable to false then the thread1 also sees the change and will stop but this is not happening at the output.I am seeing the same output, thread0 stops but thread1 still running. I thought both the threads should stop. Can somebody please help to clarify this? Please tell me where I am wrong .

Comment: Just to make that clear: when you not use the volatile keyword it might still work (and actually it often works, that is why a lot of people dont write correct code as they don't learn from pain). Actually it might work in some cases (some JVM versions, some platforms, and some conditions depending on number of repetitions and size of the code) and not in others. So always program it correctly even when your tests pass.

Answer (score 7):

You have two instances of `Processor`, so when you do `proc1.running=false;` you are only stopping one of the threads. You need to call `proc2.running=false;` as well to stop proc2.

Each of your thread objects have their own version of the instance variable `running`. You could make this variable static and then both would stop running (assuming the threads run and hit the while condition before some other code possibly changes `running` back to true).

> I thought both the threads should stop

When your sources say that other threads should see the latest value of a volatile variable they don't mean that other Threads (as in `Thread` objects) who have an equivalent version of the variable have theirs changed. They mean that when other threads of execution try to access that variable (whether it's in a `Thread` object or any other kind of object) that they will see the latest value.